# how can i repeat the wowjs animation when scroll up and down in angular 2 or 4

Tags: angular

When i installed the wowjs animation into my project it renders  once when scrolling.is there any way to repeat the wowjs animation while scrolling up and down in angular 2 or 4?

Comment: You could create a directive for that and use `@HostListener` to listen to `scroll` event on the `window` object.

Comment: can you show an example ?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-hostbinding-and-hostlistener-in-angular

Refer to the above example.

Comment: not working when adding wow js animation with ngclass

Comment: can you try it and post the code ?

Comment: Okay I will create a plunkr once I achieve the required functionality it.